# AVFoundation - Get grayscale image from Y plane (kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, avfoundation, grayscale

I'm using AVFoundation to take a video and I'm recording in `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` format. I want to make grayscale image directly from the Y plane of the YpCbCr format.

I've tried to create `CGContextRef` by calling `CGBitmapContextCreate`, but the problem is, that I don't know what colorspace and pixelformat to choose.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{       
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);        

    /* Get informations about the Y plane */
    uint8_t *YPlaneAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);

    /* the problematic part of code */
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(YPlaneAddress,
    width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCVPixelFormatType_1Monochrome);

    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext); 
    UIImage *grayscaleImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage];

    // process the grayscale image ... 
}
```

When I run the code above, I got this errors:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 1-component color space; kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast; 192 bytes/row.
```

PS: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you shouldn't go via a `CGContext`. Instead, you should create a data provider and then directly the image.

Another mistake in your code is the use of the `kCVPixelFormatType_1Monochrome` constant. It's a constant used in video processing (AV libraries), not in Core Graphics (CG libraries). Just use `kCGImageAlphaNone`. That a single component (gray) per pixel is needed (instead of three as for RGB) is derived from the color space.

It could look like this:

```
CGDataProviderRef  dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, YPlaneAdress,
      height * bytesPerRow, NULL);
CGImageRef newImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 8, bytesPerRow,
      colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it right that this is the fastest approach to get a grayscale image from camera?

Comment: @user961912: Accessing the video frame in YpCbCr is supposed to be fast because it's the native format (according to a WWDC presentation). For the following steps, it depends what you finally do with the image. For several applications (like barcode scanning), you don't need to create a CGImage nor a UIImage.

Comment: Hey Codo, Thank you for this answer! I'm trying to achieve a bit of "same" result, the difference is that i'm trying to achieve the grayscale effect, on each frame(Live video stream), any chance you can direct me to the right direction?

Comment: Your requirement of a *grayscale effect* isn't very specific. But a good library with many useful effects is [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).